# How can I use a installed version of Maven with eclipse

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, m2e

I have downloaded Apache-Maven-3.0.4 in zip format and extracted to a directory called My Documents\Software.I have set Path variable to point to the Maven\bin directory.Now when I am checking from command prompt `mvn` command is working only inside Maven\bin directory.

I want to use Maven with eclipse.Do I have to download  eclipse m2e plugin separately or can I make use of the already installed Maven-3.0.4. If I install eclipse m2e plugin where can I find installed m2e plugin ?

In which directory should I put my project  to `mvn package` command  to work?

This may sound silly,but I am new to Maven.Please help.

Comment: I have also installed eclipse m2e plugin from eclipse->Help->Install new software.But I can not find the m2e installation folder.
I want to package one existing project into jar file.How should i do it?

Answer (score 3):

Go to `window->preference->maven->installation`.
click on `Add`. Here, you can specify external maven installation, rather internal.
[image]

But you need to install m2e plug-in for this.

Comment: Thanks!! I have got m2e plugin installed.

Comment: Thanks!! I have got m2e plugin installed.
But how can I package an existing project with pom.xml file  into jar file.I am searching for a solution but unable to get it.Please help.

Comment: is your existing project is maven compatible?

Comment: Yes..my existing project is maven compatible and has its _pom.xml_ file.I just have to edit the _pom.xml_ to change the jdk level and have to package the project into a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

are you using my eclipse or simple eclipse???

there is an option when u right click on project to add maven capabilities

look at this tutorial...find configure option on right click

[link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/0.16)

Regards
Anshul Katta

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE version Indigo JavaEE.Right clicking on the project is not showing any _add maven capabilities_

Comment: hmm i also searched ...seems like there is no option bro..to add maven explicitly after creating project....will update you as soon i find something abt it !!  keep googling

Comment: @Anshul..Thanks.I am searching for it.

Comment: look at this tutorial...find configure option on right click

http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/0.16